# Memory allocation in linked lists

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

When I created a linked list, I've made a function which tells the difference of the memory address of the current ptr and the head ptr, but why is it happening that the difference is coming different when I run my program on a Mac, and different when I run it on windows?

Comment: Because they use different algorithm to manage heap?

Comment: Why should you care what the memory addresses are?

Comment: I was given an assignment that's why.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the memory (heap), how does the computer allocate each node of the linked list inside the memory (heap), on how the computer manages the heap. For instance, on Windows, it will allocate at a certain address in memory and on a Mac at another one.

Consider also that even if you run your program on two Windows computers, you can find that the address might be different.

Best regards,
Denny